# Group last rows in a single one summing values

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql table:

```
date       | client | total
2015-01-01 | john   | 85.00
2015-01-01 | alfred | 35.00
2015-01-01 | georgy | 125.00
2015-01-01 | linda  | 42.00
2015-01-01 | alex   | 76.00
2015-01-01 | john   | 94.00
2015-01-01 | john   | 75.30
```

I wanted to group by client name calculating total sum amount and percent, so I made this query:

```
SELECT client, total, round(total*100/t.th,1) as percent 
FROM ( 
SELECT client, sum(total) as total 
FROM mytable 
WHERE date='2015-01-01' 
GROUP BY `client`) c 
JOIN ( select sum(total) as th from mytable 
WHERE date='2015-01-01') t 
order by percent desc
```

It works great obtaining this result:

```
client | total | percent
john   | 254.3 | 47.8
georgy | 125   | 23.5
alex   | 76    | 14.3
linda  | 42    | 7.9
alfred | 35    | 6.6
```

But I don't know if it's possible to sum last rows and group in a single one obtaining a result like this, for example:

```
client | total | percent
john   | 254.3 | 47.8
georgy | 125   | 23.5
others | 135   | 28.8
```

I would like to know how can I modify my query to obtain this result.

I'd like some help.

Comment: What are your criteria? Do you want exactly the two highest totals, then "others", or something else?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, like the example or if I have more rows show some first rows and then "others".

Comment: Yep, perfectly possible

Comment: Right, but the point I am trying to make is, define "some first rows". You can't tell the computer "some first rows", you have to tell it exactly what to do. Is it always the first _two_ rows, or something else?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Of course I will define that number of rows, in the example it's the first two rows.

Comment: @NekoLopez: So you need it to be a configurable number? And it may change?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, only a static number